# Games of Mikhail Tal under the influence of alcohol

Tags: famous-games, tal

It is commonly known that Mikhail Tal was an alcohol addict and also had a morphine addiction for a short time.

Are there any games where he played under the influence of drugs that affected his play, or had any troubles regarding this matter with an arbiter?

Comment: Here is one (Tal was White) 1.f4 e5 2. g4 Qh4 mate

Comment: @magd Do you have any references/backround information for this game? Because i haven't found it in a database.

Comment: No here is another one though. 1.e4 e5 2.Qh5 Nf6 3.Qxf7+ Kxf7 4.Na3 Nc6 resigns

Comment: @Don He is trolling I guess :)

Comment: Tal was Black in that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I [William Hartson] remember him vying for first place with another Soviet grandmaster in a tournament in Holland. On the night before the final round they began buying each other drinks and lining up the empties on the table. When I left them at around 2am, Tal had the remains of 11 drained brandies, his rival had 11 empty rum-and-cokes. They continued for another two hours. At 8.30 in the morning, Tal trotted downstairs to start the last round looking fresh and relaxed. He won easily to take first prize, while his drinking companion was happy with a quick draw.

Source: [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/obituary-mikhail-tal-1530878.html)

I'm going to search for this game when I get home this evening.